# Visual Studio: Custom name for "App.config" in project, not outside project?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, configuration

As the title suggests, I'd like to rename "App.config" inside the project to a different name other than the default one.
I know it gets renamed to the project name after you build the solution, but it bugs me that I can't give it a diferent name inside the project, before I build...

Example:
My solution name is "Test123", and I'd like to have the config file named "Test123.config" before the project gets built. I don't care what name it has afterwards.

Okay. I've redone everything and I have the app.config file with the following structure in my project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <configuration>
        <configSections>
            <sectionGroup name="userSettings" type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
                <section name="Codex.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
            </sectionGroup>
        </configSections>
<userSettings>
    <Codex.Properties.Settings>
        <setting name="Location" serializeAs="String">
            <value>0, 0</value>
        </setting>
    </Codex.Properties.Settings>
</userSettings>
```

After I rename it to "Codex.config" inside the project, and I debug the application I get this error when running (and I also get it when I try to close the application from the "X" button (when doing "Properties.Settings.Default.Save();"):

```
A first chance exception of type 'System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException' occurred in System.Configuration.dll
```

Comment: This is strange. I've renamed it, and now it works, but I can't understand why. Before I asked this question, after I had tried everything, it gave me a "first chance exception whenever I launched/closed the application, and it would freeze; but not it works just fine... I can't understand why...

Comment: Everything is fine now, except the config file has nothing saved in it once I close the application, even though I save the application last known location on screen when closing it. Before it used to have a nice XML styled data, but now it is empty even after debugging, when it should contain something.

Comment: I've redid everything, and the project generated a new app.config file, with information in it, but now, after renaming that to "Codex.config" it doesn't work and it throws a first chance exception, and the application fails to close from the "X" button.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the pre-build event so VS copies the file and renames it

`xcopy "$(ProjectDir)YourCustomNameInTheProject.config" "$(TargetDir)$(AssemblyName).exe.config*"`

Comment: Did you even read everything I wrote in the post? I was referring to the name IN the project, not AFTER it is built.

Comment: Yes but it will make VS copy the file if it has a different name IN the project. VS will not copy the file if it is not called App.config

Comment: I've done what you said, and not it doesn't throw any more errors, but it still doesn't change the default 0,0 from the Codex.config file to the last known one (value which is saved when closing the application).

Comment: Modified the default 0,0 value of Location inside the Codex.config file and now I get a ton of errors like: "Could not find schema information for the element 'userSettings'."